# must be enable as a Publisher

Tags: sql-server, replication, sql-server-2017

I installed SQL Server 2017 on Centos 7 and used MSSM GUI for database replication configuration.

when the distribution configuration process was successful until the end but when creating a publisher, the problem started when I right clicked on

> replication > New > Publication... and an error appeared as below

[image]

> must be enable as a Publisher before you can create a publication. In the following dialog box. enable this server as a pblisher.

I have enabled it and still getting the same error.

I hope someone can help me. Thank you

Comment: What type of Replication are you trying to do (Transactional, Snapshot, Merge, or Peer-to-Peer)?

Comment: Share output of   select @@version

Comment: @J.D. I use Transactional

Comment: @AndreySamykin this is the version - Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU28) (KB5008084) - 14.0.3430.2 (X64)   Dec 17 2021 14:30:27   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Linux (CentOS Linux 7 (Core))

Answer (score 1):

On SQL Server 2017 and earlier versions. It **is not possible** to create replication using **IP** addresses.
With SQL Server, you can connect to the engine using ServerName, like:

```
example1:

servername

-- For instance name server
example 2:
servername\instancename

example 3:
servername\MSSQLSERVER2017
```

Don't use IP addresses, just what you need.
Then you see Boom, everything is good, and a new publication has been created.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. While it did not directly solve my issue, it got me on the right track. Turns out that localhost is just as invalid as an IP address, and I had to use the machine name. Thanks.